# Как определить, что сервис стартует впервые?

Tags: android

Как определить, что сервис стартует впервые?

Comment: что понимается под словом "впервые"? вообще в мире, на конкретном устройстве, в текущей сессии или просто он не был запущен.

Comment: можно в него счетчик вставить )

Comment: понимается под словом "впервые"- на конкретном устройстве

Answer (score 4):

Сервис может создать файл и при запуске проверять существование файла на устройстве. Если нет файла - впервые, если есть то нет.

Comment: Дополню: смотрите в сторону [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: Кстати да, это верно, и намного лучше чем файловый метод :)

Comment: Всему вас учить - молодежь...

Comment: да вы оба чет выдумываете. чем вам неугодила просто переменная интового типа, которя будет внутри этого потока считать кол-во возврата в него или булевая - посмотрел на нее, фолс - впервые, тру - уже был запущен

Comment: переменная интового типа же не будет существовать после перезагрузки телефона и старта сервиса?

Comment: @Barmaley все были когда-то "молодежь", почему бы не спросить тех, у кого есть опыт, а кому-то вопрос может показаться полезным!

Comment: @Barmaley за SharedPreferences спасибо

Comment: @script_kid я здесь как раз для помощи молодежи